# scrollLeft not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I am trying to make the scrollwheel scroll the page horizontal. Like windows 8 metro interface and the new myspace website.

I just can't get it to work in internet explorer (10). My JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/88dRJ/4/

I already tried to remove overflow to make scrollbars visible. Microsoft states in their documentation of doScroll that it won't work with hidden scrollbars. I prefer hidden scrollbars.

Javascript

```
var mouseWheelEvt = function (e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    if (document.body.doScroll) {
        document.body.doScroll(event.wheelDelta > 0 ? "left" : "right");
    } else if ((event.wheelDelta || event.detail) > 0) {
        document.body.scrollLeft -= event.wheelDelta || 120;
    } else {
        document.body.scrollLeft -= event.wheelDelta || -120;
    }
    return false;
};
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseWheelEvt);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseWheelEvt);
```

EDIT: To clarify I would prefer a solution without jquery or other libaries.

Comment: did you already try `document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= ` for IE ?

Comment: Woow thanks a lot that was indeed the problem. So strange I wouldn't think ie10 also didn't support document.body.scrollLeft (can you make it an answer)

Comment: you could check this code if it works in IE http://jsfiddle.net/88dRJ/8/  is yes i'll include it in the answer. i don't have IE right here so i can't test myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for IE you need to use `document.documentElement` instead of `document.body` to access/modify `scrollLeft` or `scrollTop`

`document.documentElement.scrollLeft -= event.wheelDelta || 120`;

Comment: I just adjust them both to get cross-browser scroll. Works in chrome and ie10

Comment: @automaticoo i would not adjust both. because if e.g. MS thinks it should support both in IE on time, you would get a "double" scroll distance.